# Safety net Api Error when downloaded from play store

Tags: android, security, kotlin, mobile, safetynet

I have implemented a SafetyNet attest check when launching the app. It works fine when I run the release version from Android studio and detects (for eg.) the emulator from the device correctly. However when I download the same version from the Play store, it fires the failure listener every time, on a lot of legit devices.

It is a restricted API and works fine when run locally on those same devices.

If you check the image, the 33.75% error rate is when I have used this from the play store.
[image: Screenshot]
Any idea what could be happening different with the same code when running in app downloaded from the Play store?

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue!

For anyone using 'App signing by Google Play', make sure you add the SHA-1 provided by Google Play to the API restrictions in the API Console.

You should find this in 'App Signing' in the app on the Play Developer Console.